# Finding valid sequences in a list based on specific conditions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a list of scores represented as a cell array in MATLAB, and I need to extract valid sequences from this list based on certain conditions. The scores can be one of three stages: 'Rain', 'Cloud', or 'Sun'.

The conditions for a valid sequence are as follows:

For a sequence of 'Sun' stages, the sequence must have a length of at least 7.

For a sequence of 'Rain' or 'Cloud' stages, the sequence must have a length of at least 7, and all stages within the sequence must be either 'Rain' or 'Cloud'.

I have tried implementing the following code, but it does not provide the correct results for all cases:

```
scores = {'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Rain'};
sequence_start = 1;
num_scores = numel(scores);
valid_sequences = [];
for j = 1:num_scores
    stage = scores{j};
    
    if strcmp(stage, 'Sun')
        if j == num_scores
            sequence_length = j - sequence_start + 1;
        else
            sequence_length = j - sequence_start;
        end
        
        if sequence_length >= 7
            valid_sequences = [valid_sequences; sequence_start+1, j];
        end
    elseif ismember(stage, {'Cloud', 'Rain', 'Thunder'})
        sequence_length = j - sequence_start;
        
        if sequence_length >= 7 && sum(ismember(scores(sequence_start:j), {'Cloud', 'Rain', 'Thunder'})) >= 7
            valid_sequences = [valid_sequences; sequence_start+1, j];
        end
    else
        sequence_start = j;
    end
end
if (num_scores - sequence_start + 1) >= 7
    valid_sequences = [valid_sequences; sequence_start, num_scores];
end
```

The output should be valid_sequences = [3, 9; 2,10] and where 3,9 represents the start and stop of Sun. I don't know why there is a 2, 10.

Here are two other test examples:
Test 2:

```
scores = {'Sun' 'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Cloud' 'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Sun'};
```

which returns:
valid_sequences =

```
 2     8
 2     9
 1     9
```

Test 3:

```
scores = {'Rain' 'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Cloud' 'Rain' 'Cloud' 'Sun' 'Cloud' 'Rain'};
```

Can you help me? I've been puzzling over this a couple of days and have asked chatgpt but have not had any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Your "Sun" condition doesn't check that the surrounding words are also "Sun".  You may be trusting in `sequence_start` for that, but you failed to reset it when you changed between the two different types of valid sequences.

Comment: `"I don't know why there is a 2, 10"` - so how can we guess why this should be in your output? Please [edit] the question to clarify why you expect specific outputs for the given test cases

Comment: please confirm: where you write 'The output should be valid_sequences = [3, 9; 2,10] and where 3,9 represents the start and stop of Sun. I don't know why there is a 2, 10.' you mean 'The output should be valid_sequences = [3, 9] .. ' ?

Answer (score 0):

The general problem of catching start and length of a given value along a sequence can be simplified to detecting `1` bursts in a binary sequence.

For words, as here asked, map words to numbers and then assign `1` to the sought word, and `0` to any other word.

Following I have put together some solutions to catching `1` bursts or pulses and respective lengths available in the Mathworks forum:

**1.-**

```
labeledMatrix = bwlabel(data); 
measurements = regionprops(labeledMatrix, 'Area');
allAreas = [measurements.Area];
```

**2.-**

```
function [start, len, k1] = ZeroOnesCount(v) 
%
% Determine the position and length of each 1-string in v,
% where v is a vector of 1s and 0s
% Derek O'Connor 21 Sep 2011
%
 n = length(v);
 start = zeros(1,n);            % where each 1-string starts
 len = zeros(1,n);              % length of each 1-string
 k1= 0;                         % count of 1-strings
 inOnes = false;
 for k = 1:n
     if v(k) == 0               % not in 1-string
         inOnes = false;
     elseif ~inOnes             % start of new 1-string
         inOnes = true;
         k1 = k1+1;
         start(k1) = k;
         len(k1) = 1;
     else                       % still in 1-string
         len(k1) = len(k1)+1;
     end
 end
```

**3.-**

```
function [start, val, len, rn] = RunsCount(v)
%
% Determine the length of each val-run in v,
% where v is a vector of 'values'
% Example 1: RunsCount([2 2 2 1 1 9 8 8 3 3 3 3]) gives
% start     1     4     6     7     9
% val       2     1     9     8     3
% len       3     2     1     2     4
% Example 2: RunsCount(['aaaabbaacccbbb']);
% start     1     5     7     9    12
% val      97    98    97    99    98
% len       4     2     2     3     3
%
% Derek O'Connor 22 Sep 2011
%
 n = length(v);
 val = zeros(1,n);           % run value
 len = zeros(1,n);           % run length
 start = zeros(1,n);         % pos. in v where run starts
 start(1) = 1;
 rk = 1;                     % number in run
 rn = 1;                     % number of runs
 for k = 2:n
     if  v(k) == v(k-1)      % in run
         rk = rk+1;
     else                    % end of run
         val(rn) = v(k-1);
         len(rn) = rk;
         rk = 1;             % v(k) is start of
         rn = rn+1;          % next run
         start(rn) = k;      % position of start in v
     end
 end
 val(rn) = v(n);             % last run
 len(rn) = n - sum(len);
```

**4.-**

```
function len = CountOnes(v) 
n      = length(v);
len    = zeros(1,n);         % length of each 1-string
k1     = 0;                  % count of 1-strings
inOnes = false;
s      = 0;

for k = 1:n
  if v(k)                    % not in 1-string
    s       = s + 1;         % increase the counter
    inOnes  = true;
  elseif inOnes              % leave the ones block
    k1      = k1 + 1;
    len(k1) = s;
    s       = 0;             % reset the counter
    inOnes  = false;
 end
end
len = len(1:k1);
```

**5.-**

```
function len = CountOnes_vectorized(v) 
v   = diff([0, x, 0]);
len = findstr(v, -1) - findstr(v, 1);
```

**6 -**

```
function len = CountOnes2(v) 
n   = length(v);
len = zeros(1, ceil(n/2), 'uint32');
j   = 0;

k = 1;
while k <= n
  if v(k)
    a = k;
    k = k + 1;
    while k <= n && v(k)
       k = k + 1;
    end
    j      = j + 1;
    len(j) = k - a;
  end
  k = k + 1;
end
len = len(1:j);
```

**7.-**

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0] 

B = cumsum(a)
tf = B(2:end) == B(1:end-1) & A(1:end-1)==1
result = diff([0 B(tf)])
```

**8.-**

```
[B, N] = RunLength(x)
Result = N(B == 1);
```

`RunLength` is a MEX function available [here](https://%20https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41813-runlength)

**9.-**

```
function r = Jos(x)
B  = cumsum(x);
tf = B(2:end) == B(1:end-1) & x(1:end-1);
r  = diff([0 B(tf)]);
end
```

earlier versions:

**10.-**

```
v =  [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1] 
v2 = zeros(size(v)); % Initialize vector of same length.
props = regionprops(logical(v), 'Area', 'PixelIdxList');
for k = 1 : length(props)
  v2(props(k).PixelIdxList(1)) = props(k).Area;
end
```

**11.-**

```
a = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]; 

c = a(end);
for k = length(a)-1:-1:1
  a(k+1) = c * (1 - a(k));
  c      = a(k) * (c + 1);
end
a(1) = c;
```

**12.-**

```
a = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]; 

c = a(end);
for k = length(a)-1:-1:1
  if a(k) == 0
    a(k+1) = c;
    c      = 0;
  else
    a(k+1) = 0;
    c      = c + 1;
  end
end
a(1) = c;
```

**13.-**

```
out     = zeros(size(a)); 
aa      = [0,a,0];
ii      = strfind(aa, [0 1]);
out(ii) = strfind(aa, [1 0]) - ii;
```

**14.-**

```
k    = find([true, diff(a) ~= 0]);      % Indices of changed values 
r    = zeros(size(a));
r(k) = a(k) .* diff([k, length(a)+1]);  % Distance of changes
```

**15.-**

```
out = double(diff([~A(1);A(:)]) == 1); 
v = accumarray(cumsum(out).*A(:)+1,1);
out(out == 1) = v(2:end);
```

**16.-**

```
out = zeros(size(A)); 
ii = strfind([0,A(:)'],[0 1]);
out(ii) = strfind([A(:)',0],[1 0]) - ii + 1;
```